# Sampling from Gaussian distribution subject to a quadratic inequality constraint

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, constraint

Would it be possible to generate samples $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ subject to an inequality constraint $x^\top Q x/2 + b^\top x \le c$, $Q = Q^\top \succeq 0$. We also know, that and $\mu^\top Q \mu/2 + b^\top \mu < c$. Thank you!

Comment: what about just using rejection sampling?

Comment: @jld Yes, that's natural.  The problem is that for $n\ge 2$ it could be grossly inefficient unless executed very cleverly.  The problem worsens as $n$ increases.